# Ios Push notifications Solution

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

**New to swift coding!**
Need some help with Push Notification.
I just implemented the push notification in my app. 
I have a Device token id, key id and the software which I am using is Push notification Tester.
My question is once I upload my app on the store will I able to trigger the notification to all the users through the tester app or do I need to write a  script for that??

Any help is appreciated!!

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print("Device Token: \(token)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to register: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: You can use a script as well as your tester app. But Script is the easiest solution.

Comment: You need to store the tokens somewhere so that your script can send the notifications

Comment: did you consider using some framework for push notifications?
alert: I'm developer of one of those frameworks

Comment: Why don't you try something like Firebase for push notifications, is free, and can extend functionality easily